# Split file into parts of roughly equal size but considering 2-line blocks

Tags: bash

I've got a file, that contains hundreds of thousands of lines, that look like this:

```
>something
somethingelse
>something2
somethingelse2
>something3
somethingelse3
>something4
somethingelse4
>something5
somethingelse5
>something6
somethingelse6
>something7
somethingelse7
>something8
somethingelse8
>something9
somethingelse9
>something10
somethingelse10
```

etc.

Every 2 lines are paired, so for example, this would be considered 1 entry in the file:

```
>something
somethingelse
```

I want to be able to split this into `n` files, of roughly equal size. However, while splitting, each file should keep the entries together: the `n` split parts should contain a roughly even number of entries, rather than splitting merely on the lines. For example, if I were to try to split this into roughly 4 files, I'd want something like:

File part1

```
>something
somethingelse
>something2
somethingelse2
>something3
somethingelse3
```

File part2

```
>something4
somethingelse4
>something5
somethingelse5
>something6
somethingelse6
```

File part3

```
>something7
somethingelse7
>something8
somethingelse8
```

File part4

```
>something9
somethingelse9
>something10
somethingelse10
```

Which file parts the remainder 2 ended up in don't really matter as long as the files contain roughly the same number of entries, and the entries are kept together, so **not**:

file1:

```
>something
somethingelse
>something2
```

file2:

```
somethingelse2
>something3
somethingelse3
```

I've considered using the `split -l` command, however as far as I know it's limited to either: splitting this file into hundreds of thousands of files each only containing 2 lines, or splitting the file into parts of roughly equal number of lines, but where an entry may be split up (the first line ending up in one part and the second line in another part).

Is there any simple way that I'm just overlooking to do this with bash commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well what you want to achieve, you only need to use `split -l` with any *even* number of lines.

If `N` is the total number of lines and `P` is the number of parts you want to create, I would probably use something like:

```
split -l $((N/P + (N/P) % 2))
```

where `+ (N/P) % 2` ensures that you get an even number